# Field-images wont be migrated in a migrate-upgrade --- Not sure if it's a bug

Tags: migrations, upgrading

I try to Migrate-upgrade a D 7.44 site to D 8.1.3 and all seem to be migrated besides API images (i.e images uploaded in image fields).

Images uploaded in CKeditor with IMCE, on the other hand, appear just fine.

I am not sure if that's a bug because AFAIK, tens if not hundreds of sites were upgraded without that a problem.

---

Details that might help you conclude if this is a bug:

1. The D7 site files folder permissions is 755.
2. The D8 site files folder permissions is 777.
3. The `node__field_image` table in the D8 DB is empty (i.e zero rows).
4. The files path I gave in the Migrate UI module is `/var/www/html/benia.biz/sites/default/files` as in the first image here.
5. The second image describes a warning I saw while migrating and it might be associated to the problem. This warning deals with duplicated image paths, though I have no clue why it would appear.

---

**Image1:**

[image]

**Image2:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included a critical piece of information here which was not included in https://www.drupal.org/node/2759309:

You specified your file path as `/var/www/html/benia.biz/sites/default/files`.

Actually it should be `/var/www/html/benia.biz/`.

The sites/default/files portion is automatically included in the file paths by the migration process.

- In the correct path note you have an extra slash (one after the benia.biz so it's `benia.biz/`); Missing this slash as well could make the migration process miss the images.

Comment: Finally I fully migrated !!! Thank you Mike Ryan !!!